# Changing Java version using jenv in a shell script

Tags: java, react-native, jenv

I have a `React Native` project where I have a script in which I need to change the `Java` versions before and after the script has been executed. I basically need to change to `Java 1.8` to run commands connected to the `android` `sdkmanager`, and then switch back to `Java 11` when done.

I am currently using `jenv` to manage `Java` versions. If I do this in the Terminal at the root of the project using either of the following commands, it works:

```
jenv local 1.8
jenv local 11.0
```

However if I use the same in my bash script files, which I run via `yarn`, it doesn't work. The script file looks something like, `<project_root>/scripts/my_script.sh`:

```
jenv local 1.8;
java -version;

# Some code here involving sdkmanager...

jenv local 11.0;
java -version;
```

The `java -version` correctly displays that the Java version has changed, but the instructions in between with the `sdkmanager` don't pick up on the change. Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help/insights are welcome.

Comment: Does jenv changes JAVA_HOME environment variable? Check it before and after script.

Comment: @Viktor I just checked.`jenv` doesn't change the `JAVA_HOME` when it's run from the script, but it does if I change it directly in the terminal. Not sure why that is. Maybe I should find a way to directly change `JAVA_HOME` instead of using `jenv`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Android command tools use same JDK as Android Studio.

Relevant documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

> STUDIO_JDK - Sets the location of the JDK with which to run Android Studio. When you launch the IDE, it checks the **STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME, and JAVA_HOME** environment variables in that order.

Something in your scripts sets these variables up and 'jenv' doesn't override them.

Comment: Hmm. Seems unlikely. I removed all of the code that didn't involve changing the Java version and it still doesn't work. It does work if I manually set the JAVA_HOME from within the script though. The issue seems to lie with `jenv`.